# Print Data tables of Cucumber Java on terminal/console

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to create some scenarios with step definitions that contain some data tables [Cucumber Data Tables](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#data-tables)

My tests get executed correctly and I get the scenarios and step definitions printed on the console/terminal, but not the data tables. In Ruby all the data tables get printed along with the Scenarios and Steps definitions, but not in Java

I'm using maven. I'm calling the test scenarios with:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="pathtoFeatureFile.feature" ,plugin = { "pretty" }, monochrome = true)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

use **toString()** method of the DataTable or directly use the dataTable variable in System.out.println() to print the DataTable defined in the Feature File as it is

```
    public void the_board_should_look_like_this(DataTable expectedTable) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Printing Datatable : \n"+expectedTable.toString());
        expectedTable.diff(board);
    }
```

or

```
public void the_board_should_look_like_this(DataTable expectedTable) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Printing Datatable : \n"+expectedTable);
    expectedTable.diff(board);
}
```

Comment: This prints the datatables in a different time than the scenarios.